# How to read lines of a file?

Tags: java, io

I got a file contains two lines:

```
aaaaa
bbbbb
```

I used these lines to read each lines:

```
    File f=new File("D:\\xxx.dat");
    FileReader fr = new FileReader(f);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
    String str;
    String tmpp="";
    while ((str = br.readLine()) != null) {
         if(str=="bbbbb")
         {
         System.out.print(str);
         }
    }
```

but I got nothing as a result.why?

Comment: Use search before posting, it's not optional ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are using "==" instead of equals method.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of

```
if(str=="bbbbb")
```

write

```
if(str.equals("bbbbb"))
```

String equality is a common mistake for beginners and for programmers from other languages.

Comment: you are right. I just switched from C# to java!

Answer (score 1):

You're using == to compare the strings.

String is not a primitive type, so you should use `.equals()` method.

When you compare two Strings with ==, it will compare the two objects and return false because they don't point to the same String object (even though they represent the same thing).

To understand better why is that take a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/73021/2576857 , it gives a great explanation IMO.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your input file first line contains more than "bbbbb".
Please check the value of str before If sentence and use equals method to compare strings (to compare values instead of references)